# Error when loading csv file

Tags: micropython, file

So this is my code; I have both my python file and csv file in my raspberry pi pico already as you can see in the image.[image] However, when I run it, it returns an error.

```
#from machine import Pin, I2c
#from ssd1306 import SSD1306_I2C
#import framebuff
import time
from sys import stdin

w = 128
h= 32

#oled = I2C(0,scl=Pin(1),)

df = []
delim = ','
with open('colordata.csv','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        df.append(line.rstrip('\n').rstrip('\r').split(delim))

def color_recognition(r,g,b):
    color = 'Unknown'
    names =[]
    index = []
    threshold = 50
    for i in range(len(df)):
        R = int(df[i][4])
        G = int(df[i][5])
        B = int(df[i][6])
        diff = abs(r - R) + abs(g -G) + abs(b-B)
        if diff <= threshold:
            index.append(diff)
            names.append(df[i][2])
    
    
    if len(index)>0:
        result = sorted(index)[0]
        for j in range(len(index)):
            if index[j]==result:
                color = names[j]
    else:
        pass
        

    return color
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 16, in <module>
MemoryError: memory allocation failed, allocating 4096 bytes
PROBLEM IN THONNY'S BACK-END: Exception while handling 'Run' (thonny.plugins.micropython.mp_back.ManagementError: Command output was not empty).
See Thonny's backend.log for more info.
You may need to press "Stop/Restart" or hard-reset your MicroPython device and try again.


Process ended with exit code 1.
```

What can I do to fix this calamity?

Comment: Can you find any related info in the mentioned log file?

Comment: How big is the csv file?

Comment: @CoderMike 864 x 6

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: @dirb File sizes are conventionally in bytes...

Comment: `calamity` ... a hurricane wiping out a town is calamity ... your problem is miniscule in comparison